# Почему VS2017 при publish создает конфиги на все сборки?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Поставил Visual Studio 2017 и практически сразу заметил одну неприятную особенность. "Новая" студия создает конфиги на все сборки, используемые в проекте.

Например: 
Солюшен имеет следующую структуру (в каждом проекте есть свой файл конфига):

```
ProjectA (не ссылается ни на кого)
ProjectB (содержит ссылку на ProjectA)
ProjectC (содержит ссылку на ProjectA)
ProjectD (содержит ссылку на ProjectB и ProjectC)
```

Если отбилдить такой солюшен в новой студии, то смотрите какой какое количество конфигов эта зараза создает:

```
ProjectA (app.config)
ProjectB (app.config, ProjectA.dll.config)
ProjectС (app.config, ProjectA.dll.config)
ProjectD (app.config, ProjectA.dll.config, ProjectB.dll.config, ProjectC.dll.config)
```

Это прикол именно 2017-ой студии. За VS2013 или VS2015 такого замечено не было. В них меньше конфигов было. Как отучить VS2017 на каждый чих конфиги создавать? Может какая-то настройка где-то есть? Кто как лечил?

Comment: Уберите зависимости, и вероятно оно перестанет их создавать.

Comment: Если я убери зависимости в свойствах солюшена, то при билде/паблише сборки этих проектов не будут создаваться. VS 13 и 15 имеют такие же настройки солюшена, но лишние конфиги не тянут.